# "elem.type is undefined" in typewatch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, typewatch

I downloaded the typewatch file from the [github](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) page, put it in my vendor/assets/javascripts file and required it the normal way in my application.js  Then I do the following code (as shown on the github page)

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        callback: function(){ alert("changed search text"); },
        wait: 50,
        highlight: true,
        captureLength: 2
    }
    $('#search').typeWatch( options );
});
```

and it doesn't work at all.  It also breaks the [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) functionality I have.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is getting pretty irritating :(

Update:

Firebug gives the following error: "elem.type is undefined" in line 38 of the plugin [code](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch/blob/master/jquery.typewatch.js)

Comment: Is there any kind of javascript error Chrome's WebInspector (or FF's Firebug) shows you in the javascript console?

Comment: on line 36 put a `console.log(elem)` and now say what you see in console

Comment: in addition to showing the jquery error, it shows the html of the form I'm trying to keyup:

<form id="search" method="get" action="/concerts" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: its searching for `type="text"` in your HTML. and you are passing the form . rather pass the input field to it

Comment: the html is generated by rails, am I supposed to explicitly pass the type when I need it?

Comment: rail have also generated an input field. and you can specify an html id for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you reported `<form id="search" method="get" action="/concerts" accept-charset="UTF-8">` is shown at `console` in comments. which means its searching for a `type` attribute of the dom. and you are passing the `form` dom to it. rather you should pass the `input` field. like `$('#search_input_field').typeWatch(options);`